# Changing Background for Night & Day using php?

Tags: php, dynamic-css

I'm working on a tumblr page. I have two different backgrounds for the html page and I want the DAY background to display from 7am to 8pm and the night background to display from 8pm to 7am.

I decided to do this in php, but i'm a total newb when it comes to php. My friend sent me an example code that I could use. But I have no idea what to do with it. Can you guys help.

Here's the example code.

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/css');

date_default_timezone_set("America/Vancouver");
$now = date('G');

if ($now < 12) {
    $bg = '#FFFFFF';
} else {
    $bg = '#000000';
}
?>

body {
    background: <?php echo $bg; ?>;
}
```

Comment: did you consider checking sunset time instead of explicitly specifying day and night times? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sunset.php

Answer (score 6):

The `date()` will return the server local date/time, which means that if your server is in the US, a user from Eastern Asia or Australia for example, will see the wrong background.

I know this isn't what you were looking for, but I would suggest doing it with JS, which runs user-side rather than server-side, and therefore the timezone will not matter because the script will get the user's time, not the server's time. The script would look something like:

```
var localDate = new Date();
if (localDate.getHours() > 7 && localDate.getHours() < 20) {
    document.bgColor = "#fff";
} else {
    document.bgColor = "#000";
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
body {
    background: <?php echo $bg; ?>;
}
```

to:

```
<body style="background-color: <?php echo $bg; ?> !important;">
```

You PHP Code seems to be fine to me. Note that, it will display white background from 12:00 noon to 12:00 midnight. Try the following code for keeping white background from 7:00 AM to 8:00 PM and black other times (as Aaron said).

Replace:

```
if ($now < 12) {
    $bg = '#FFFFFF';
} else {
    $bg = '#000000';
}
```

with:

```
if ($now < 7 || $now > 20) {
    $bg = '#000000';
} else {
    $bg = '#FFFFFF';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `date` function you're using is returning the 24 hour format of the current hour. Next, in the conditional you should modify that to check what range you're in. If `$now` is between 7 and 20 you can set it to the daytime background. Otherwise, set it to the night time. Let me know if you need more details for doing this.

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/css');

date_default_timezone_set("America/Vancouver");
$now = date('G');

if ($now > 7 && $now < 20) {
    $bg = '#FFFFFF';
} else {
    $bg = '#000000';
}
?>

<body style="background-color:<?php echo $bg; ?> !important;">
 <!-- Your HTML code here -->
</body>
```

Comment: lol, yes. I noticed that and was already researching how to tell php to do that. I just need to know how to how to implement it onto the html web page. It's confusing me a little. Especially since the html is not on my server.

Comment: wow,it's that easy? thank you for this. How would I call the php file since the html is on a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this

your php:

```
    function getUKTime() {

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    $time = date('H');
    $style = "";

    if ($time >= 6 && $time <= 18) {
        $style = $style . "day";
    }
    else {
        $style = $style . "night";
    }

    echo $style;
}
```

in your html:

```
<div id="uk" class="<?php getUKTime(); ?>">
    <h1>U.K.</h1>
</div>
```

then just style your .night or .day classes

Answer (score 0):

You can set different css files, one for day time and the other for the night.

```
$date = getDate();

// check day or night
// it's day by default
$css = "css/main.css";

if ($date['hours'] < 7 || $date['hours'] > 20){
    // is night
    $css = "css/main-night.css";

}
```

Then, in the `<meta>` tag, that define the page's style file.

```
    <link href="<?= $css ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```