# how have different background images for different times in the day

Tags: php, css, image, background

I'm looking to be able to have different background colors for different times in the day. Would that be possible with php, or would I have to use JavaScript? The thing I'm trying o get at is having a background photo for the morning, afternoon, evening and night of each season I want to try to make the code look like this but I'm not completely sure if this approach will work.

```
$ty=timeOfYear("D") 
$background=__________
$t=date("H")

if ($t>"9"[$ty>"100")
________________

elseif  
__________________
```

Comment: Set the class on `body` (based on your condition) and use CSS to style it incorporating the class into the appropriate selectors. (Of course, setting the class in JavaScript might be better ..)

Comment: You have to keep in account the user's time zone. Are you just relying on the server's time zone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357634/changing-background-for-night-day-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think JavaScript would be the best choice  in your situation.

Get inspiration from here

https://github.com/beiyuu/beiyuu.github.com/blob/master/old-index.html